# Multiple objects with same material Qt3D

Tags: python, qt, qt3d

I dynamically generate 3D objects with the same material (around 100 objects). Creating a material for each individual object consumes a significant amount of memory. Is there a way to use one "global" material and apply it to all of the objects? When I attempted to create a material object and add it as a component to the objects, the code didn't work as expected (no errors, but the code turned off immediately after being turned on). I'm using PySide6 with Qt3D and Python 3.11.4.

Comment: Are the 3D objects using the same mesh? Then you could go for [instanced rendering](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qt3d-experiments/tree/master/instanced). And did you try to run the code in debug mode? Sometimes you then get the error messages. I'd also try to create only 2 objects and see if it works then. Maybe it's the number of objects that is the problem. And if you don't add the material the code works, right?

Comment: Make sure the material has a valid parent. If you add an unparented material to an entity/mesh as component this entity is internally set as the materials parent. Therefore if this entity/mesh is destroyed the material becomes invalid for other entities.

Comment: Post a [mre]. What is the parent of a ```QMaterial``` object?